# Dynamically select a comparison operator (>=, <=, etc) in a conditional?

Tags: php

```
if (foo >= bar) baz();
```

But let's say sometimes baz(); needs to be run when `foo <= bar`, or `foo == bar`... and let's say that this comparison operator is grabbed from, say, a db table, and placed into a variable: `$param = ">="`.

Is there any way you could modify the first line to use `$param`, besides a switch-case with multiple if statements?

In my code, `baz();` spans about a whole bunch of lines, and would become an organizational nightmare were I to manage it by hand.

Comment: So make baz() actually be a function. Problem solved.

Comment: So you want the parameter string to be parsed into an operator and use it in the if statement??

Comment: Unaware of a native way to do this, I would write a function that takes args $val1, $val2, $param, do the switch and ifs in there, and return the boolean. The boolean then goes into your main if statement. As a function, you could reuse this if the pattern appears again, too.

Comment: @Billy - but that's less fun than exposing my code to scripting attacks...! ;)

Comment: The eval thing isn't because of attacks. It's because eval is a maintainability nightmare.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function lt($a, $b)
{
  return $a < $b;
}

 ...

$relops = Array(
  '<' => 'lt',
   ...
);

echo $relops['<'](2, 3);
```

Comment: I never knew PHP could interpret a string as a function name like that.  Neat.

Comment: $relops = array( '<' => (function($a,$b){return $a < $b; })); - would that work? (php5.3 of course) or do you have to invoke the "in" function?

Answer (score 4):

I solved this using:

```
function doComparison($a, $operator, $b)
{
    switch ($operator) {
        case '<':  return ($a <  $b); break;
        case '<=': return ($a <= $b); break;
        case '=':  return ($a == $b); break; // SQL way
        case '==': return ($a == $b); break;
        case '!=': return ($a != $b); break;
        case '>=': return ($a >= $b); break;
        case '>':  return ($a >  $b); break;
    }

    throw new Exception("The {$operator} operator does not exists", 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [eval()](http://php.net/eval)?

```
$param = ">=";
eval ("if (foo $param bar ) baz();");
```

Read more on the documentation page for the eval function.

EDIT:

Indeed, as others have mentioned, if there are alternatives, they are almost always better than eval(). If used, it must be used with care.

Comment: Oh god no. But it does answer the OP's question... +1.

Comment: No, please don't suggest `eval` when there are safer alternatives.

Comment: Ha! I love the comments... now, what if I used eval(), and made sure to sanitize the input so that it was only one of the expected inputs?

Comment: @Julian: That wouldn't be any better. Eval is evil and needs to be avoided wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

elaborating on my comment:

```
function variableOpComparison($v1, $v2, $o) {
    if ($o == '!=') return ($v1 != $v2); // could put this elsewhere...
    $operators = str_split($o);
    foreach($operators as $operator) {
        switch ($operator) { // return will exit switch, foreach loop, function
            case '>': if ($v1 > $v2) return true; else continue; break;
            case '<': if ($v1 < $v2) return true; else continue; break;
            case '=': if ($v1 == $v2) return true; else continue; break;
            default: throw new Exception('Unrecognized operator ' . $operator . ' in ' . $o);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```